# how to separate an integer number from a string in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sometimes in a HTML file, we have a `<p>` tag that shows the price of a product. For example the price is `"1,200,000 Dollar"`. Now a user added this product to the cart. I want that the webpage display the total price in the cart.

Now in JavaScript I want the program separate the number of price from string and put that in a variable. Here in the example that I said the `<p>` tag shows `"1,200,000 Dollar"`. Now I want to put just the number(in the example the number is `1,200,000`) in a variable to calculate the total price later.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you need the thousands separator? JavaScript integers do not have thousands separators.

Comment: Are you sure there will be only one space between the value and currency?

Comment: `number = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML; number = number.replace(/ Dollar/g, ""); number=number.replace(/,/g, ""); number = parseInt(number); alert(number);  // output: 1200000`

Comment: What makes you think your numbers have commas at all? You only add those at the point where they turn into HTML text for the user to see, they don't exist on the JS side where you're working with the numbers.

Comment: If I am catching up with this question, you don't need a variable outside your function. All you need is a button and an onclick event. The onclick event calls a function that checks input and writes to the <p>.

Comment: You shouldn't use the HTML text to hold your application data. Put it in JavaScript objects, or HTML attributes.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it worked for you

Comment: Avoid using var and use let and const for variables as var may cause problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a split function in this case.

```
const currencyString="1,000,000 Dollars";
const currencyNumber=Number(currencyString.split(' ')[0].replace(/,/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the below answer your question...

```js
var input = '1,200,000 Dollar';
var output = Number(input.replace(/[^0-9\-\.]/g, ''));
```

First we remove all non-digit characters with `.replace` method and then create a new `Number` value.

**A few other usage examples:**

```js
function stringToNumber(string) {
  return Number(string.replace(/[^0-9\-\.]/g, ''));
}

var inputs = [
  '1,000,000 Dollars',
  '$1,000,000.50',
  '-50.12 USD'
];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i], stringToNumber(inputs[i]));
}
```